# Does Skyrim: Legendary Edition have anything except the old DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I understand that Skyrim: Legendary Edition will have all the DLC that has been previously released however will there be any other extras?

Box art (unrelated, but it helps):

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. It is simply a compilation pack.

The additional difficulty level and removal of level cap were added to vanilla Skyrim in a patch (patch 1.9), according to the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Jimeee/Skyrim_1.9_beta_update_adds_Legendary_difficulty_and_raises_level_cap_%28Updated_Apr_8th%29) (which links to the official blog as a source)

Additional quote from the [Bethesda Blog](http://www.bethblog.com/2013/04/25/legendary-release/):

> Coming to Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, and PC on June 4th for $59.99 (European territories will see its release on June 7th), this package includes the most up-to-date version of the original game (employing the 1.9 title update),as well as the game’s three add-ons: Dawnguard, Hearthfire, and Dragonborn.

Info from the [Bethesda Blog about update 1.9](http://www.bethblog.com/2013/04/08/skyrim-1-9-update-on-consoles/) (note that it states PS3 and Xbox, but the patch was released for PC before the consoles. The console one is unchanged except for specific bug fixes):

> **NEW FEATURES**
>
> Legendary difficulty setting
>
> Legendary Skills – Skills of 100 can be made Legendary. This will reset the skill to 15, return its Perks and allow the skill to affect leveling again. This effectively removes the overall level cap.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [official website](http://bethsoft.com/en-us/games/skyrim_legendary_edition), the Legendary edition contains the following:

> The Legendary Edition includes the original critically-acclaimed game, official add-ons – Dawnguard™, Hearthfire™, and Dragonborn™ – and added features like combat cameras, mounted combat, Legendary difficulty mode for hardcore players, and Legendary skills – enabling you to master every perk and level up your skills infinitely.

Comment: This is incorrect. See my answer for correct details.

Comment: This is perhaps more a quote of  Bethesda being creative with their marketing rather than an incorrect *per se*, however the features mentioned are indeed included in a patch for the normal version as well as the Legendary Edition meaning they are nothing exclusive

Comment: @Rory It sounds like there's nothing you can get in Legendary Edition that you cannot get in vanilla skyrim besides the level cap thing for skills. Is this correct?